# WP7 - Is it Possible to change the Panorama from horizontal to Vertical scroll?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

In my app now i am using Panorama to show many items. It showing horizontal scroll. But i want to show in vertical. It is possible to change the scrolling from horizontal to vertical?
I have try like this.

```
        <controls:Panorama.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                </StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama.ItemsPanel>
```

But it return error at execution time.
Is there anyway to change change the Panorama from horizontal to Vertical scroll?

My try using Listbox.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="testUIContainer" Margin="2,0,2,0">
        <ListBox>
            <StackPanel>
                <!--<Rectangle  Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="Header" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FF01A1DB" />-->
                <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>

                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBoxes1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I have try Scroll Viewer also. It is also not working.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="testUIContainer" Margin="2,0,2,0">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ScrollViewer.Content>
                <ListBox>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!--<Rectangle  Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="Header" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="480" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="#FF01A1DB" />-->
                        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                                <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                            </Border>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>

                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentDetails,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="listBoxes1" Width="476" BorderBrush="#00410D0D">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="5" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Wheat" BorderThickness="1">
                                                <Image  Name="ListPersonImage" Source="{Binding PersonImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                            </Border>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" Name="firstName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" Name="lastName" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" Name="age" Width="200" Foreground="White" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22"  />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer.Content>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

No ! there is no way to scroll it vertically. But you can use listbox or you can make your own control i.e custom control.

Comment: Hi @HmXa.. Thanks for your reply. What about 'Pivot Control'. Is it possible in 'Pivot Control'? Actually my requirement is, In Android Play store when we select one application it will move to one page. In that page we can see the reviews, Screen shots, Similar apps etc. Like that only i am trying to do. I want to add items like that and i want scroll in vertical. Is it Possible?

Comment: Hi ! unfortunately there is no way to scroll panorama and pivot control vertically. but you can put listbox inside your panorama and pivot control.

Comment: @user2845346: from my understanding you can made it by yourself. example you can use listbox on your main page. put a stackpanel inside your listbox. put listbox inside stackpanel and bind some images. and set it scrolling to vertical or horizontal as your wish.

Comment: Hi @HmXa. I have attached my code as per your hint. But it's not working. I can not see the second Listbox. Because the first list box have more than 10 list items. My code is right or where i have to do correction?

Comment: is second listbox not showing ? i think you should set the height of first listbox to auto. kindly check this and tell me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your second ListBox has the Grid.Row set to 1. It should be 0, from what I can tell. Your Scrollviewer is in Grid.Row="0" by default, meaning your stackpanel is also in 0, meaning your first listbox is in 0...you get the picture. :)

Sorry if I'm incorrect. :(

edit: Also, your listboxes seem to be exactly identical, aside from the name you assign to each one. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish? Why would you need two separate listboxes to show all the same data?

Comment: Hi @user3007447.. In my application i am trying to implement one page like Android Play Store Page. In Android play store, when user click one application the page will navigate to another page. In that page we can see the reviews, Screen shots, Similar apps etc. User will scroll in vertically and see all the data. Like that only i am trying to do. But I can not achieve that. I have tried Panorama, Pivot Pages. In this pages i can only scroll in horizontally.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this or if it is possible. Sorry.